# Angular ng-click get params from jquery trigger event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

With jQuery I can pass params to trigger event and get them from a function. Like this:

```
$('div').trigger('click', [1])

$('.classname').live('click', function (event, param) {
    alert(param);
})​;
```

Can I catch the same param using ng-click?

Comment: have you gone through the docs?

Comment: Yes. I can emit event, using scope but this is not I want.

Answer (score 0):

## simple answer

yes you can like this

```
<button ng-click="yourtask(task.id)">remove</button>
```

where task is the scope and id is part of that scope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but doesn't look like this. 
In angular you must configure the `ngClick` directive with a function of your `$scope` that can receive paramenters like so:

Controller

```
function myController($scope){
    $scope.myClickHandler = function(param){
        console.log(param);
        //code here
    };
}
```

Html

```
<button ng-click="myClickHandler('foo')">Click</button>
```

if you need to trigger this function handler it can be invoked like a normal function.

On controllers:

```
$scope.myClickHandler('bar');
```

On views (once your view in on myController scope):

```
myClickHandler('bar');
```

Comment: My problem is that I must to fire event using .trigger(). I can't run a handler manually by click on element.

Comment: Well, can you give us more context?